# Add extra space between tabs in tab layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I have the Figma model, but can't do right, in all cases that I've tried, I've got too wide tab indicator or too compressed. I think, maybe exist some solution to add extra space between tabs. I can`t add the image to this post, i put link on my google photo. You will see 2 photo, left photo - What i need

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CiwR7DemvCcQxWFz6

XML for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.QuizActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBolotoButton"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bellota_bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Проверим знания!"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/circle"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBolotoButton"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="32dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:clickable="false" >

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/quizViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
class QuizAdapter(activity: AppCompatActivity, val itemsCount: Int)
    : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemsCount
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return QuizFragment.getinstance(position)
    }
}
```

Activity

```
class QuizActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var testArray = arrayListOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
//    private var QuizPageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
//        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
//            Toast.makeText(this@QuizActivity, "Selected position: ${position}",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//        }
//    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.quizViewPager)
        val pagerAdapter = QuizAdapter(this, testArray.size)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

/*
Method for concatenation  ViewPager and tabLayout
 */
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, quizViewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text=testArray[position]

        }.attach()
```

Fragment

```
class QuizFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        const val ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE"

        // Method for creating new instances of the fragment

        fun getinstance(page: Int): QuizFragment {
            val fragment = QuizFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val position = requireArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE) + 1

        textViewFragment.text = "Fragment #$position"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val viewfragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false)
        var position = requireArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE)

        val textView = viewfragment.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewFragment)
        textView.setText("Fragment #${++position}")

        return viewfragment
    }
}
```

Comment: Idk but try setting the width of tab layout to match parent

Comment: thanks for response, but i`d tried this one, and layout how i said, become too stretched

Comment: i`ve add screen  into google photo (link above ), for case when i change to match parent and app:tabGravity="fill" , that is my problem